# Chrome not changing device-width when I resize the browser window

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am working on a PC with screen resolution 1600x900.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Page title</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        @media screen and (max-device-width : 600px) {
            body { background-color:#F00; }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body></body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I am trying to develop a resposive version of the site and while developing I want to use Chrome on my PC. I was expecting that when I resize my browser to width less than 600px, the media queries will run, but it seems to think my device width is 1600px and it never changes. How to make it fire the media queries while I resize the window on my PC?

Answer (score 8):

Remove "device" from `@media screen and (max-device-width : 600px) {` :http://jsfiddle.net/7rSzr/

Making it:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 600px) {
    body { background-color:#F00; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"I want to use Chrome on my PC"

You can change `device-width` in the settings of the Chrome Developer Tools. Refresh your page after that and admire the red background ;)